# 401 Unauthorized : Missing required argument values

Tags: entities, services, 8

I am using [Services Entity Module](https://www.drupal.org/project/services_entity)

I am trying to POST to http://example.com/rest/entity_message

and Getting this error 401 Unauthorized : Missing required argument values

Can anyone tell what I should enter in body area ?

Comment: Have you read the docs to see what arguments are required? How do you supply them?

Comment: How are you sending the values? There are quite a few different ways/things that could be wrong or right but the question is vague. Also, for the Services Entity Module there are two different controllers that you can use so we also need that information.

Comment: I am unable to find Docs that's why don't know exactly what arguments are required.. If you can help me I would appreciate @Mołot

Comment: @burnsjeremy I am not sure but I think you are asking about values of Body ? Here is what I have entered in the Body area :
{
"message_field": "Hellooo",
}
Please tell me what else information you need ?